# Analytics Experiment Parser blocking error

Tags: google-analytics

I've tried to implement google analytics experiments to one of my pages. I added the following code:

```
<!-- Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->
<script>function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}(function(){var 
k='122644017-3',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie;
 if(l.search.indexOf('utm_expid='+k)>0)return; function f(n){if(c){var 
i=c.indexOf(n+'=');if(i>-1){var j=c. indexOf(';',i);return 
escape(c.substring(i+n.length+1,j<0?c. length:j))}}}var 
x=f('__utmx'),xx=f('__utmxx'),h=l.hash;d.write( '<sc'+'ript src="'+'http'+
(l.protocol=='https:'?'s://ssl': '://www')+'.google-
analytics.com/ga_exp.js?'+'utmxkey='+k+ '&utmx='+(x?x:'')+'&utmxx='+(xx?
xx:'')+'&utmxtime='+new Date(). valueOf()+
(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+ '" type="text/javascript" 
charset="utf-8"><\/sc'+'ript>')})(); </script><script>utmx('url','A/B');
</script>
<!-- End of Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->
```

to the head but my console gives the following output:

```
A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga_exp.js?utmxkey=122644017-3&utmx=&utmxx=&utmxtime=1475762834841, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity. 
Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.
```

I have tried to google this error, even search this place before posting, but I have no idea why I am receiving this. Is there any one here that could point me in the right direction to solve this?

Comment: Related information (no solution, though) : https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/08/removing-document-write

Comment: Did you solve this?